# GeoServer: Set sequence of layers to be rendered in a WMS

Tags: geoserver

how do I configure the sequence of layers in my GeoServer workspace such that when I read the layers in WMS in, say~ Tableau (below) or QGIS, the list of the layers available to be checked is in the sequence I need?

In ArcGIS Server, this can be easily set by aligning the layers in ArcMap before publishing it to the ArcGIS Server.

However, I can't seem to find such a configuration in GeoServer Admin.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution for this.

I found out that arrangement of layers to be displayed on the client can be set by naming the layer "Name" field in order.

E.g., (1 Coastline), (2 Waterbodies), (3 Roads) will display coastline as first layer, followed by waterbodies and roads.

Comment: that's fine until the 10th layer!

Comment: can start with 01, 02 etc. rather than 1, 2 :p

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of the layers is solely at the control of the client. GeoServer just provides a list of layers that the client can pick and display in any order it likes.

If you need to combine certain layers in a specific order you could use a [`LayerGroup`](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html).

Comment: Merging as a layer group will essentially "merge" them into a single layer and prevent the user from selecting / deselecting the layers of interest. Unfortunately, for clients like Tableau Desktop, it just takes the layers from GeoServer and displays it as a fixed order which is not what I want. I guess it is strange that ArcGIS desktop / server provides such functionality yet this is missing in GeoServer. :(

Comment: why does the order matter? I guess you can add a feature - https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer

Comment: hi, let's say I have a country polygon and a road polyline. If the roads is ordered after the country, and I on both layers, the country polygon will be stacked on top of the road, thus covering the latter.

Comment: Will mark your answer as correct since you have pointed out the limitation for my scenario. Thanks!